# How to force the Spring Test Context Framework to Reinitalize Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 4 Test context framework to do some integration testing of a statefull spring service. Here is the code that distills the problem to its most basic form.

```
@Service
public class StatefullService {
    private List<String> items = new Vector<>();

    public void add(String item){
        items.add(item);
    }
    public List<String> currentState()
    {
        return new ArrayList<>(items);
    }
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring.xml" })
public class Test1 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired 
    private StatefullService service; 

    @Test 
    public void addA()
    {
        service.add("A");
        Assert.assertTrue(service.currentState().contains("A"));
    }   
}
```

The Spring Test Context framework will cache the Spring Context so that subsequent test cases will not need to rebuild the spring context.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring.xml" })
public class Test2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private StatefullService service; 

    @Test
    public void addD()
    {
        Assert.assertTrue(service.currentState().isEmpty()); // assertion fails here 
        service.add("D");
        Assert.assertTrue(service.currentState().contains("D"));
    }
}
```

When `Test2` runs `addD()` method will fail because the `StatefullService` already has "A" in the list. Adding `@DirtiesContext` to `Test1` will cause spring to know that `Test1` is going to dirty the context and so subsequent tests should re-init spring.

`@DirtiesContext` says that the current test dirties the context, **is there an annotation that says that the context is dirty?**

Something like `@RefreshCachedContext` that would force spring to refresh the cached context no matter what is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're trying to make: `@DirtiesContext says that the current test dirties the context, is there an annotation that says that the context is dirty?`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want an annotation that tells the test framework to re-init spring always when that test class runs.

Comment: Does `@DirtiesContext` not do that for you?

Comment: When '@DirtiesContext'  is put on Test2 the test will fail because the re-init will happen when the next class runs, In the above example '@DirtiesContext' must be put on Test1 to get Test2 to pass.

Comment: @ams but that's the expected behavior of `@DirtiesContext`, you should put it on those tests that will dirt the context (in this case, Test1). Apart from this, you should use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of technically deprecated `Vector` for handling concurrency operations in your List.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a way that will force Spring to not use the cached context when loading the specific test. Correct?

Comment: @geoand your interpretation is correct

Comment: Can't you simply call `refresh()` on the application context before any test is run?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `@DirtiesContext` on the test that actually dirties the context but instead you want to force Spring to reload the context used in the current test, you could add a dummy profile (this workds because context caching is based on the location of the configuration and the profiles used).

I would **not** use this solution myself in code since it definitely has a hacky feeling to it, but it would work for what your are trying to do.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles("dummyProfileNotUsedElsewhere")
public class Test2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private StatefullService service; 

    @Test
    public void addD()
    {
        Assert.assertTrue(service.currentState().isEmpty()); // assertion fails here 
        service.add("D");
        Assert.assertTrue(service.currentState().contains("D"));
    }
}
```

One more reason you would **not** want to use something like this is that if you start getting in the habit of using it a lot, the execution speed of your tests will be significantly reduced